# Protractor's getText() method does not include text-transform done in a ::first-letter pseudoselector

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

Our QA team uses protractor 5.4.2 for feature / integration tests on an angular web app.  Part of the app is receiving data from our API, then using just CSS applying a "sentence-case" class to it to force the text into desired capitalization: first character upper case, all following characters lowercase--regardless of input format.

This works fine for the app being displayed in the browser.  But when our tests extract the element text with element.getText(), the returned string has had the 'lowercase' text transform done, but **not** the uppercasing of the first character.

CSS style:

```
/* convert something to sentence case */
.sentence-case {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.sentence-case::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Sample HTML

```
<section id="testSect">
  <h2>Test Section</h2>
  <br/>
  <div class='sentence-case'>ABCDEF</div>
  <div class='sentence-case'>aBcDeF</div>
  <div class='sentence-case'>Abcdef</div>
  <div class='sentence-case'>ABCDEF</div>
</section>
```

Protractor test code:

```
describe('sentence-case transform', () => {
it('with GetText', () => {        
    let foo: ElementArrayFinder = element.all(by.css('#testSect div.sentence-case'));
    browser.get('http://localhost:4200/testPage');
    foo.each((bar: ElementFinder) => {
        expect(bar.getText()).toBe('Abcdef');
    })
})
})
```

Test results:

```
  sentence-case transform
  × with GetText
    - Expected 'abcdef' to be 'Abcdef'.
    - Expected 'abcdef' to be 'Abcdef'.
    - Expected 'abcdef' to be 'Abcdef'.
    - Expected 'abcdef' to be 'Abcdef'.
```

- Is this a limitation in protractor's support for pseudo-selectors?
- Is there any workaround in protractor to get the final transformed text value?

Comment: Try doing the `browser.get()` before initializing `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the same behavior recently and while we could work around it there are some options you may be able to work with. You should be able to get the text of an element as it appears (after the text-tranformations) by sending some javascript commands to the browser using `executeScript`.

```
let textDiv = await element(by.css('div[class]')).get(0);
browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;", textDiv);
```

`outerText` should also work in this context.

If you really want to get the pseudo-selectors you can run a command like the following also.

```
//returns uppercase
browser.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':first-letter').getPropertyValue('text-transform');", textDiv);
```

**Code you can try**

```
    let foo = element.all(by.css('#testSect div.sentence-case'));
    foo.each((bar) => {
        browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;", bar).then(innerText => {
            console.log(innerText)
            expect(innerText).toBe('Abcdef');
        })
    })
```

Comment: Well, that gives us a workaround to use, though it feels like extra "cruft" just to deal with what should be a simple function (get the text as it's rendered by the browser after all CSS transforms).  We may limit that script validation in only the few cases where we need "letter exact" validation

Comment: @sciguyCO I agree, while doing some investigation into this I did find several github threads [including this one](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3778) which request to have this supported in webdriver but it doesn't seem to be something that is priority for them at the moment